# How to change Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects localization

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-installer

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with extension [Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects&ssr=false#qna) and I wish to customize texts displayed by the installer. I know I can select localizations from a rather small list in Setup/Properties and also I can modify the "welcome text" part (see image below) but I want to translate the whole installer (even e.g. the Next button) to a language not shown on the localization list and I also wish to use UTF-8 encoding for characters like "ő" and "ű" which are shown as "o" and "u" with this method.

[image: This opens the User Interface window where I can modify some, but not all texts]

Can I achieve the above with the said tools?